# How can I limit the threads netty uses for client connections

Tags: java, netty

Is there a way to limit how many threads netty uses for client connections (Netty is the client which connect to a remote server). I am using 1 `NioEventLoopGroup` which is passed into each `Bootstrap`. Each of those Bootstraps gets the same `ChannelInitializer` reference (I used to create different initializers for each Bootstrap, but it seems to work fine sharing the same reference). I am connected from my Java application to many hardware devices which act as the server.

I have noticed that currently up to 16 threads are used (I am on an 8 core machine, from what I have read Netty uses 2 times the number of cores by default). They are named `nioEventLoopGroup-2-1` to `nioEventLoopGroup-2-16` from what I see in my logging. The 17th server I connect to will run on `nioEventLoopGroup-2-1` again.

1) Is there a way to change this default of threads used?

2) Any idea why the group starts to count from 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you pass 1 to the NioEventLoopGroup and share the instance between the bootstraps only one client will be used.

Answer (score 0):

I saw in the source code that it is also possible to set it via a System property: `io.netty.eventLoopThreads`