# Create thousands of Netty clients without also creating thousands of threads

Tags: java, netty, c10k

I have created a fairly straight forward server using Netty 4.  I have been able to scale it up to handle several thousand connections and it never climbs above ~40 threads.

[image: number of server threads remains constant (via Java VisualVM)]

In order to test it out, I have also created a test client that creates thousands of connections.  Unfortunately this creates as many threads as it makes connections.  I was hoping to minimize threads for the clients.  I have looked at many posts for this.  Many examples show single connection setup.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22090824/how-can-i-limit-the-threads-netty-uses-for-client-connections) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12989078/netty-4-multiple-client) say to share NioEventLoopGroup across clients, which I do.  I'm getting a limited number of nioEventLoopGroup, but getting a thread per connection elsewhere.  I am not purposely creating threads in the pipeline and don't see what could be.

[image: number of client threads grows with number of connections (via Java VisualVM)]

[image: threads (via Java VisualVM)]

Here is a snippet from the setup of my client code.  It seems that it should maintain a fixed thread count based on what I've researched so far.  Is there something I'm missing that I should be doing to prevent a thread per client connection?

**Main**

```
final EventLoopGroup group = new NioEventLoopGroup();

for (int i=0; i<100; i++)){
    MockClient client = new MockClient(i, group);
    client.connect();
}
```

**MockClient**

```
public class MockClient implements Runnable {

    private final EventLoopGroup group;

    private int identity;

    public MockClient(int identity, final EventLoopGroup group) {
        this.identity = identity;
        this.group = group;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            connect();
        } catch (Exception e) {}
    }

    public void connect() throws Exception{

        Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap();
        b.group(group)
         .channel(NioSocketChannel.class)
         .handler(new MockClientInitializer(identity, this));

        final Runnable that = this;
        // Start the connection attempt
        b.connect(config.getHost(), config.getPort()).addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
            @Override
            public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) throws Exception {
                if (future.isSuccess()) {
                    Channel ch = future.sync().channel();
                } else {
                    //if the server is down, try again in a few seconds
                    future.channel().eventLoop().schedule(that, 15, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As has happened to me many times before, explaining the problem in detail made me think about it more and I came across the issue.  I wanted to provide it here should anyone else come across the same issue with creating thousands of Netty clients.

I have one path in my pipeline that will create a timeout task to simulate a client connection rebooting.  It turns out it was this timer task that was creating the extra threads per connection whenever it received a 'reboot' signal from the server (which happens every so often) up until there was a thread per connection.

**Handler**

```
private final HashedWheelTimer timer;

@Override
protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Packet msg) throws Exception {

    Packet packet = reboot();

    ChannelFutureListener closeHandler = new ChannelFutureListener() {
        @Override
        public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) throws Exception {
            RebootTimeoutTask timeoutTask = new RebootTimeoutTask(identity, client);
            timer.newTimeout(timeoutTask, SECONDS_FOR_REBOOT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        }
    };

    ctx.writeAndFlush(packet).addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
        @Override
        public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) throws Exception {
            if (future.isSuccess()) {
                future.channel().close().addListener(closeHandler);
            } else {
                future.channel().close();
            }
        }
    });

}
```

**Timeout Task**

```
public class RebootTimeoutTask implements TimerTask {

    public RebootTimeoutTask(...) {...}

    @Override
    public void run(Timeout timeout) throws Exception {
        client.connect(identity);
    }

}
```

Comment: SUrely Netty provides a timeout of its own?

Comment: @EJP, [HashedWheelTimer](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/util/HashedWheelTimer.html) is a Netty class.  By default it uses defaultThreadFactory().